# Wordpress Docker site can't be reached

Tags: wordpress, docker

I'm trying to create a local WordPress environment using Docker and existing WordPress db dump. PHPMyAdmin is loading correctly and the db is in that but the localhost:8000 where I am trying to load the site says it can't be reached. Is there something I am missing in this `docker-compose.yml` file?

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    volumes:
      - ./data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wpdb
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment: 
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wpdb
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      WORDPRESS_DB_PREFIX: unti54
    volumes: 
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3333:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORT: password
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that both the db and the wordpress volume are correct and the logs aren't showing any errors about them, check the definition of the wordpress ports. You use quotation marks, but in the db service you don't. Try to execute the script without those quotation marks.